# Scons; Construction Variable for assembler include directory;

Tags: c++, assembly, build, scons

I'm wonder is there is some equivalent of `CPPPATH` for compilation of assembler files?

```
CPPPATH=include_dirs
```

works perfectly for `.cpp` files but it seems do not apply for `.S` files. I got error message like "no such file or directory"

So is there some sort of 'ASPATH'?

Thanks

PS: As workaround currently I use `ASFLAGS` with `-I/my_path` but I don't really like it...

ADDED:
this approach works (ASFLAGS)

```
asm_dirs = '-I' + gen_build_dir + gen_file_dir + ' '  #relative path here
as_flags = asm_dirs + env['ASFLAGS']
t = env.Program('boot.elf', sources, CPPPATH=include_dirs, LIBPATH=lib_dirs, LIBS=libs, ASFLAGS=as_flags,
    LINKFLAGS=link_flags)
```

this approach doesn't (CPPPATH)

```
include_dirs += [   #add path to 'CPPPATH'
    gen_build_dir + gen_file_dir + ' '
]
t = env.Program('boot.elf', sources, CPPPATH=include_dirs, LIBPATH=lib_dirs, LIBS=libs, LINKFLAGS=link_flags)
```

Detailed script:

```
asm_cppflags = ('-S -Wno-invalid-offsetof ')
gen_build_dir = 'build/ProductXYZ/rel/'
gen_file_dir = 'OS/UserAccess/'
gen_file_name = 'UserAccess_HandleSysCall_ConstGen'
src_full_name = gen_file_dir + gen_file_name + '.cpp'
obj_full_name = gen_build_dir + gen_file_dir + gen_file_name + '.o'
dst_full_name = gen_build_dir + gen_file_dir + gen_file_name + '.h'
a = env.Object(src_full_name, CPPFLAGS=asm_cppflags, CPPPATH=include_dirs)
gen = env.Command( target = "HEADER", source = "",
    action = "cat " + obj_full_name + " | " + gen_script + " > " + dst_full_name )
Depends( gen, a )
asm_dirs = '-I' + gen_build_dir + gen_file_dir + ' '
as_flags = asm_dirs + env['ASFLAGS']

link_script = 'Targets/LinkerScripts/%s.ld' % product
link_flags = ('-nodefaultlibs -nostartfiles -Wl,-T -Wl,%s -Wl,-Map -Wl,LINK.MAP ' % link_script) + env['LINKFLAGS']

t = env.Program('boot.elf', sources, CPPPATH=include_dirs, LIBPATH=lib_dirs, LIBS=libs, ASFLAGS=as_flags,
        LINKFLAGS=link_flags)
Depends(t, link_script)
```

Comment: Which assembler are you using? Which platform?

Comment: assembler for ARM, GNU GCC toolchain, under mac os.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no workaround necessary, you can use `CPPPATH` for assembler (`as`/`gas`) as well.
When running the simple `SConstruct`

```
env = Environment()
print env.Dump()
```

as "`scons | grep AS`" you see (amongst others) the definition of "`ASPPCOM`"

```
'ASPPCOM': '$CC $ASPPFLAGS $CPPFLAGS $_CPPDEFFLAGS $_CPPINCFLAGS -c -o $TARGET $SOURCES'
```

and how it uses the variables "`$CPPFLAGS`", "`$_CPPDEFFLAGS`" and  "`$_CPPINCFLAGS`" as well. The latter picks up the "`CPPPATH`" since it's defined as (run `scons | grep CPPINCFLAGS`)

```
'_CPPINCFLAGS': '$( ${_concat(INCPREFIX, CPPPATH, INCSUFFIX, __env__, RDirs, TARGET, SOURCE)} $)'
```

I suspect there is some other error in your build scripts (`as` not found in `PATH`?), but this is impossible to tell without seeing a) your SConstruct, b) how you call `scons` and c) the full verbatim error message.

Maybe you want to join us and subscribe to our User Mailing list at scons-users@scons.org (see http://scons.org/lists.html)? We could discuss this problem further there, with a lot of knowledgeable users to help you out (not all of them are active on SO).

Comment: I added part of the script for reference. But still I tried to use `CPPPATH` again with the same result.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not enough for me (or anyone else) to be able to reproduce your problem. As long as you don't take the time to provide some sort of working and self-contained minimal example (MWE) I can't comment on what's wrong here. For example, I don't know what `gen_build_dir` includes or how it's defined. Maybe you *think* that these questions are irrelevant and shouldn't be asked...then I'd recommend that you re-read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then reconsider your take on this.

Comment: description is updated. It'd be difficult to post a whole script since it's more than 150 lines long. FYI `a = env.Object()` is to generate intermediate files, which is used later.  `t = env.Program()` should has PATH to these intermediate files. Intermediate files are on place.

Comment: Still not an MWE, sigh. I don't see how `sources` is defined...and by the way: for a too long script you could use "pastebin" and simply post the link in the question. Wouldn't that be an option?

Comment: the problem is not in the list of source files. `sources = [ 'main.cpp', 'Debug.cpp', 'CPPSupport.cpp', etc]`